# How come whimsical date creation react differently in the TypeScript playground?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date, typescript-playground

If I create a whimsical date in Node 12, I will get a different result than in the TypeScript playground (in staging, there: https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200729#), why ?

In Node 12 on Repl.it or on my computer

```js
console.log(new Date("2020-02-30")) // will display 2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

In the staging TypeScript playground

```js
console.log(new Date("2020-02-30")) // will display null
```

It transpiles to

```
"use strict";
console.log(new Date("2020-02-30"));
```

Comment: What does it transpile to?

Comment: I've updated my question to display what it transpiles to. The only difference is that the strict mode is activated but it doesn't do anything on dates apparently

Comment: I cannot reproduce, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200729#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUZYHcAEARAhgC6yoBEATAAxUC01NAzJaQJQtA) (I assume that's what you meant by "staging playground") logs the current date just fine. What browser are you running this in?  A `new` expression does never return `null`

Comment: I've added the URL to the staging playground

I think the "null" is the Date converted to string by the soString function

Comment: the log is working properly for me on the playground

Comment: @FrédéricEspiau Thanks but I cannot reproduce [there](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200729#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUZYHcAEARAhgC6yoBEATAAxUC01NAzJaQJQtA) either